# Как кликнуть по элементу c одинаковым class?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть две кнопки я пытаюсь кликнуть с помощью этого javascript
`document.querySelector('[class="what"]').click();` нажимаеться кнопка первая где написано Да как заставить чтобы нажмалась вторая где написано Нет?

html
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Правильным вариантом будет перебрать полученный псевдомассив методом forEach, и на каждый элемент повесить событие клика. Таким образом вам не нужно на каждый элемент прописывать вручную событие клика, так вы во все кнопки с одинаковым классом повесите слушатель.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать querySelectorAll
Таким образом вы получите список нод (NodeList).
После чего, можно для удобства преобразовать NodeList в массив.
Например:

```
let result = [];
let Nlist = document.querySelectorAll(".what");
result = [...Nlist];
           
result[0] //вернет первый элемент массива (кнопку "Да" в вашем случае). Вот по ней уже можно кликать прицельно.
result[1] // вернет вам вторую кнопку ("Нет")
```

Comment: Так на будущее, NodeList псевдомассив и у него уже есть свойство length, следовательно можно обращаться к индексу и без преобразования.